# Unable to connect 2 computers in c#

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking, network-programming

I am trying to send a message between 2 computers. I have been able to establish connection but for some weird reason i have been unable to acquire stream.

Server Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;

namespace chat_server
{
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 9999);
        server.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for client connections");
        TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
        Console.WriteLine("Client request accepted");

        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

        Console.WriteLine("The message is " + reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
 }
}
```

Client Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;

namespace chat_client
{
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient("localhost", 9999);

        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

        writer.Write("Hello world");
        Console.WriteLine("Message Sent");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
 }
}
```

My server code confirms client connection by printing client request accepted. However for some reason i am unable to acquire data from stream. Quick Help would be really appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to flush the stream in order to actually send the data.

Try:

```
writer.Write("Hello world");
writer.Flush();
```

Take a look at the MSDN docs for more information:

Synchronous socket server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y0e13d3.aspx
Asynchronous socket server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w7b7x5f.aspx

Here's a site that explains in more detail the ins and outs of sockets: http://nitoprograms.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html

Comment: `ReadToEnd` I think requires you to close the stream, so that will probably not work. You will have to nibble the data instead.

Comment: It's been a while.. You'll need to loop on the server side until it actually receives some data. I edited my answer to include some further reading, the MSDN article sends the string `"<EOF>"` at the end of their message and loops until it has read all the data and found this. Your problem is that you're trying to read from a stream straight away when there isn't any data available yet.

Comment: No problem, I couldn't believe how difficult it was to make a socket server and client the first time I did it. Especially when you want to start accepting multiple connections and tracking them. I started on a chat client like you look to be but never finished it, although those Nito articles did help me a lot. Happy coding =]

Answer (score 0):

In server side,

add `static TcpListener server;` at the top

Then `server.Start();

```
        Socket soc = listener.AcceptSocket();

        Console.WriteLine("Connection successful");
        Stream s = new NetworkStream(soc);

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(s);
        StreamWriter writer= new StreamWriter(s);

        sw.AutoFlush = true;
        sw.WriteLine("hello world");`
```

In client side

```
 TcpClient client = new TcpClient("localhost", 9999);
        Stream s = client.GetStream();
        Console.WriteLine("Connection successfully received");

        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(s);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(s);
        sw.AutoFlush = true;
        string dis=reader.readLine();
        Console.WriteLine(dis);
```

Hope it will work now.